# Android compilation Error

Tags: android, c, generics, compilation, makefile

I have compiled my android source code with following steps,
Added device tree for rpi2 in device folder
then compiled with following command

- source build/envsetup.sh
- lunch (selected rpi2 in the list displayed)
- make -j4

but I am getting the following error when I compile it

target Strip: libwebviewchromium (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libwebviewchromium.so)
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-***strip:out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so: File format not recognized***
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libwebviewchromium.so] Error 1

Kindly help.